# UILocalNotification to execute an action

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I would like to have a UILocalNotification to execute an action whenever it gets fired. What I really want to do is to update application.applicationIconBadgeNumber programmatically. Right now I do this whenever the user exits the application, the problem is that the badge number may have to change even if the user is not using the application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the badge number of your app whilst the user isn't in the app, you can set the following property of the *UILocalNotification* instance:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger applicationIconBadgeNumber
```

From the documentation:

> The default value is 0, which means "no change.” The application should use this property’s value to increment the current icon badge number, if any.

You can't execute any code when the *UILocalNotification* fires, but you can (of course) execute code if the user decides to tap on the action button if you set one, as the user will be returned to your app.

Comment: What I wanted was to execute some code in order to get the badge number dynamically. I guess I just can't.

Comment: Yea, no you have to know this at the time when you create the *UILocalNotification* instance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to read [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). Especially [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1). And finally read the [UILocalNotification Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILocalNotification), which include James' code.